# Material UI - TextField outlined doesn't render outline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have just TextField directly from material UI example page with set variant "outlined". But for some reason it doesn't render outlined variant but just "classical" one. I don't want it hack it with some custom css. I have already searched for what it may be but can't find the answer. Thanks in advance for any help

```
<TextField
   id="outlined-multiline-static"
   label="some text"
   multiline
   rows="4"
   value={value}
   onChange={onChange}
   className={classes.textField}
   margin="normal"
   variant="outlined"
  />
```

CSS

```
textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
},
```

Comment: Are you using inline css? Please check the console for any errors

Comment: you mean using `style` ? Then nope i am not

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: What version of material-ui are you using ?

Comment: @Ricovitch version 1.5.1

Comment: OK so it seems there is no "variant" prop on TextField component in 1.5.1 version : https://v1-5-0.material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: @Ricovitch right after you asked for version i have checked myself and found it that i was using wrong docs. Upon upgrade it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Upgrading it to the latest version solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using wrong version of `material-ui` (1.5.1) which did not support `variant` option. Upon upgrade to latest it works

Comment: My Material-ui version is 3.0.3 and still the variant is not working